Is it possible to use the Java 17 compiler to compile a Java Applet that calls netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow()?
I know applets are no longer formally supported.  I have some legacy code that can still run using IE 11/Edge in compatibility mode.  I can also run applets in any browser using Webswing.
My applets use netscape.javascript.JSObject to perform live connect to the page's JavaScript.
I can compile with Java 11, but in Java 17, method netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow() has been removed.  If I try to compile an applet that uses netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow() with Java 17, I get a compilation error.  Here's a sample applet and the compilation error I get:
Sample applet:
package your.package.name;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class SimpleApplet extends JApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("SimpleApplet.init()");
        netscape.javascript.JSObject win = netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(this);
    }
    
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("SimpleApplet.start()");
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("SimpleApplet.destroy()");
    }
}

Compiling with command:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\javac.exe" "C:\Users\userId\your\package\name\SimpleApplet.java"
Yields this output:
SimpleApplet.java:5: warning: [removal] JApplet in javax.swing has been deprecated and marked for removal
public class SimpleApplet extends JApplet {
                                  ^
SimpleApplet.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                netscape.javascript.JSObject win = netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(this);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method getWindow(SimpleApplet)
  location: class JSObject
1 error
1 warning

I know the netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow() method has been removed, so I figured I'd add jaws.jar to the classpath (note that jaws.jar is basically the same as plugin.jar).  Compiling with jaws.jar as follows:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\javac.exe" -cp "C:\Users\userId\jaws.jar" "C:\Users\userId\your\package\name\SimpleApplet.java"
Yields this identical output:
SimpleApplet.java:5: warning: [removal] JApplet in javax.swing has been deprecated and marked for removal
public class SimpleApplet extends JApplet {
                                  ^
SimpleApplet.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                netscape.javascript.JSObject win = netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(this);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method getWindow(SimpleApplet)
  location: class JSObject
1 error
1 warning

It seems that the compiler is not looking at my jaws.jar.  If he did, he'd find the netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow() method.
Can I compile with Java 17?  Is there a way to force the compiler to use the jaws.jar implementation of netscape.javascript.JSObject?
A side note: The test applet above is not flagged with errors in eclipse as long as I have the jaws.jar listed before Java 17 (in Project Properties->Java Build Path: Order and Export tab).  If I move Java 17 above jaws.jar, then the IDE flags getWindow() as an error.  If eclipse can handle Java 17, then I assume javac should be able to, too.

This will all end in tears ;) Stick to what's supported, rewriting if necessary

By the way, FYI, https://cheerpj.com/

You can compile with --release 11
